# Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol Tesseract OCR C++ Using VS 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, ocr, tesseract

Have someone configured [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) c++ source-code successfully? It has 32 stars, but I am stuck to even run it as it is

While I am trying to setup the source code of `Tesseract` in my visual studio, it is giving errors in obj files, how can I edit those files, its not making any sense to me. If I do not do that then what different I should do to run it successfully at my environment (I have same specs as required by the [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract))

> 1.Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _l_dnaDiffAdjValues referenced in function _ptraConcatenatePdfToData   pdfio2.obj
>
> 2.Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _l_dnaJoin referenced in function _recogAppend   recogbasic.obj
>
> 3.Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  tesseract.exe

***I Build it with following setps :***

> 1.Downloaded from this [Link](https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract/).
>
> 2.Downloaded [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and [leptonica](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica).
>
> 3.It contains a build_tesseract.bat to build the latest tesseract version.
>
> 4.I had selected the tesseract as start up Project

here is my .cpp main file

```
#include "baseapi.h";
#include "allheaders.h";

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error states that it's not possible to run `x64/debug/zlib.lib` file. It's OK as `.lib` library file is not executable file.

Most likely, if you have no compilation errors, reason of the problem is in startup configuration. Set project where your `main.cpp` located as *[Startup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx)*.

To compile `Tesseract` you should put downloaded [Leptonica](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica) sources into `VS2015_Tesseract-master\leptonica` folder and downloaded [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) sources into `VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.04`. I assume `VS2015_Tesseract` unpacked into `VS2015_Tesseract-master` folder.

After that open `VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract.sln` and build `tesseract` project. You don't need to use `build_tesseract.bat`.

The result of `tesseract` build is `tesseract.exe`. I've put your logic of `main()` function into `main(int argc, char **argv)` in `VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.04\api\tesseractmain.cpp` file. It successfully compiled for me.

Comment: Please review my question again I had update the question thanks for your Time.

Comment: @HassanALi I've included build steps for your code into my answer, please check it.

Comment: Sure i will test it and reply you soon.

Comment: @SarahM I don't test it, but I'm sure you [can use VS2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/). VS2017 shipped with `v141` toolset, but in this Tesseract solution `v140` toolset used. You need to install this toolset to be able to build it. You can get it [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools).

Comment: I tried it with v140 but got many errors, you can check them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485671/tesseract-3-05-build-errors-in-visual-studio-2017