# Tesseract 3.05 Build errors in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, tesseract

I used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40090093/6837132) in order to make Tesseract 3.05 work on my windows10 x64 project, visual studio 2017.
I got these errors when building it:

```
    11>c:\users\mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unichar.h(164): error C3646: 'UTF32ToUTF8': unknown override specifier
11>c:\users\mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unichar.h(164): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unichar.h(164): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\genericvector.h(376): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\params.h(205): warning C4800: 'BOOL8': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(241): error C3646: 'CleanupString': unknown override specifier
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(241): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(241): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(244): error C3646: 'CleanupString': unknown override specifier
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(244): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(244): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(265): error C2065: 'string': undeclared identifier
11>c:\users\mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(265): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'cleaned'
11>c:\users\ mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(265): error C2065: 'cleaned': undeclared identifier
11>c:\users\mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(265): error C3861: 'CleanupString': identifier not found
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\unicharset.h(266): error C2065: 'cleaned': undeclared identifier
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(181): error C3646: 'VersionString': unknown override specifier
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(181): error C2059: syntax error: '('
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(181): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(183): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(183): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(134): error C2664: 'void tesseract::TessdataManager::SetVersionString(const int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'const int'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(134): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(138): error C2664: 'void tesseract::TessdataManager::SetVersionString(const int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [13]' to 'const int'
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil\tessdatamanager.h(138): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\dict\dict.h(55): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u2606' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
11>c:\users\jihed mestiri\documents\vs2015_tesseract-master\vs2015_tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\api\tesseractmain.cpp(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'simddetect.h': No such file or directory
11>Done building project "tesseract.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 9 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How to resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the time of the linked answer, project structure was changed. It's updated to Tesseract 3.05 and clear Git submodule links to the proper `Leptonica` and `tesseract_3.05` sources added.

It looks like you've downloaded master sources for both of them. At the moment [`VS2015_Tesseract`](https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract/) is not compatible with it.

Proper dependency links are: [`leptonica @ e98a794`](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/tree/e98a7941ad2af4bb838c2a5c67cafaa4503ec44b) and [`tesseract_3.05 @ 7fe95f0`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/7fe95f0705bd25959b0f645e28f311babe6871a7). Download it and try to rebuild the solution.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Now to use it in a project, I have to include libraries as usual in linker General/input or there is different way?

Comment: It depends on your use-case. If you plan to use API directly check the `tesseract\tesseract.vcxproj` project. It contains all the required options for linker and compiler.

Comment: I want to use it in order to develop an image text recognition project. I don't know if that means API directly. What should I do with  `tesseract\tesseract.vcxproj`?

Comment: `tesseract\tesseract.vcxproj` compiles into `tesseract.exe`. You can use as a sample for your application. All libraries in `VS2015_Tesseract` compiles into static libraries. Add it to your project as usual static libraries.

Comment: I added `VS2015_Tesseract\tesseract`  and  `VS2015_Tesseract\` to **Linker->general->additional library directories** but still get errors.

Comment: You should also add all the required static libraries `libtesseract.lib;giflib.lib;libjpeg.lib;liblept.lib;libpng.lib;libtiff.lib;libwebp.lib;openjpeg.lib;zlib.lib;` into **`Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`**.

Comment: After adding them, I get errors like `cannot open libpng.lib` is there something missing? maybe I have to put a new related path in Path environment variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151055/discussion-between-nikita-and-sarah-m).

Answer (score 0):

After adding in **C/C++ -> Additional Include libraries**:

```
C:\Users\Jihed Mestiri\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\liblept
C:\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\leptonica\src
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\wordrec
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\opencl
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\viewer
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\textord
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\neural_networks\runtime
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\dict
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\cutil
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\cube
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\classify
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccstruct
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccutil
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\ccmain
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\api
C:\Users\Documents\VS2015_Tesseract-master\tesseract_3.05\vs2010\port
```

as well as the directory that contains .lib files in **Linker -> General -> Additional Library directorie**s and included in **Linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies these .lib files of Tesseract and Leptonica:**

```
libtesseract.lib
giflib.lib
libjpeg.lib
liblept.lib
libpng.l‌​ib
libtiff.lib
li‌​bwe‌​bp.lib
openjpeg.lib
‌​zlib.lib
```

Compilation errors of my [test program](https://github.com/SarahMestiri/RedEyeRemover) changed to:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RedEyeRemover, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libpng.l‌​ib'
1>Done building project "RedEyeRemover.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Whereas the directory that contains libpng.lib file is included in **Linker->General**.

The parameters are taken from **tesseract/tesseract.vcxproj** that I build from [VS2015_Tesseract](https://github.com/peirick/VS2015_Tesseract)

What can be the reason behind that error? and is there a way to verify that tesseract.vcxproj is working correctly at its own? because I get errors when I compile it too on Visual Studio 2017 (using v140 = VS 2015 version for build) on x64 target.

EDIT: **SOLUTION**: I discovered that the problem was in  **Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories** where I had a **space** in one of the parent directory of the path e.g: "xxx xxx/tesseract". => avoid using paths with space.

Comment: Please check my recent posts in chat at my answer